# git: get filemodes from another branch, without changing file contents

Tags: git

I need to copy the file mode for all files in my repo from `master` to my `feature` branch.  But I DON'T want to get the file contents from `master`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but not trivial.  You will need to write a small bit of code for that.  You must also decide what you want to do about files that don't correspond: e.g., what if the tip commit of `master` has a file `mastery.txt` that does not exist in the tip commit of `feature`, but the tip commit of `feature` has a a file `featureful.dat` that does not exist in the tip commit of `master`?

Then, all you need to do is get the modes of all the paths named in the commit from which you want to copy modes, along with their names.  To do that, use `git ls-tree -r commit-specifier`.  Save the output somewhere.  For instance:

```
git ls-tree -r master > /tmp/master-info
```

View the output; note that it consists of lines of the form:

```
100644 blob <hash><TAB><path>
```

and:

```
100755 blob <hash><TAB><path>
```

There may be additional lines for symlinks (mode 120000) and submodules (mode 160000, I think) which you can ignore here.

Each 100644 means that the particular *`path`* listed after the literal <kbd>TAB</kbd> character is *not* executable, and each 100755 means that the corresponding *`path`* *is* executable.  Change the mode of the current index entry and/or work-tree file as appropriate, using `chmod`, `git update-index --chmod`, both, or some other combination of commands as appropriate.

Any files that you did not update are simply not in the selected commit; any *`path`* where it's impossible to change the mode because the path does not exist, in the work-tree and/or index, are not in the current work-tree / index (and hence presumably not in the current commit and won't be in the next commit either).  Do whatever it is you chose earlier, with these files.